# Get the first n characters of a line from a text file?

Tags: python, split, character, text-files, line

I am trying to get the first 33 characters of a line from a text file. As an example, I have the following model:

The text file looks like this:

```
['1996/01/11', '00:14:36', '267', '18', '499', '571', '426', '0', '-64.3*', '-------', '-------', '272', 'Only', 'C3']
['1996/01/13', '22:08:30', '2020', '16', '290', '278', '303', '372', '2.8*', '-------', '-------', '266', 'Only', 'C3']
```

And I want to take only the first 33 characters of it.

I tried doing this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as filehandle:
    current_line = 1
    for line in filehandle:
        if current_line > 4:
            words = line.split()
            print(str(words[0:33]) + "\n")
        current_line += 1
```

However, I did not succeed. Can you help me please?

I want to do this because I need the date, the time and also the first values in order to concatenate the date and the time into `datetime` and have the value separately.

Comment: You want the first 33 characters, but you're trying to extract the first 33 words. Don't use `line.split()`, just use `line[0:33]` to get the first 33 characters.

Comment: it woked! thank you very much!!! @Aziz

Comment: Roxana let me know if it worked and please accept this answer or let me know if you wanted something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply slice the array like that:

```
line[0:33]
```